# How to generate a JAR file without referenced libraries in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm doing *File > Export > Runnable JAR file*. And the available library handling options are "Extract required libraries...", "Package required libraries...", "Copy required libraries...". I have a huge list of referenced libraries, and all of this takes forever. I already selected the option "Copy libraries into sub-folder next to generated jar", and do not want to re-copy them every time a re-generate the jar file. How to  do this? Thanks.

Comment: File > Export > Java > JAR file, unless your summary is really inaccurate.

Comment: How does this solve my problem? And which summary are you talking about?

Comment: "How to generate a JAR file without referenced libraries in Eclipse?"

Comment: But it still seems to be exporting the libraries. There are different checkboxes (e.g. export generated class files and resources, export java source files and resources), I tried to select different options, but I have not been able to get what I want, I'm still missing something.

Comment: I'm at a loss to understand what you want. It's recreating the .jar file each time, how could you not copy them if copying them is what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any direct support for this but you could probably work around this limitation. You could remove all the libraries from eclipse so it will be invisible to eclipse. That way you don't have to export the libraries, because to eclipse they are not there. It will export with errors though because eclipse will be confused. Also, if you want to use this method you need to reimport the libraries after you exported your project.